# Separate chapter for bibliography in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, bookdown, bibliography

I am writing a book using markdown and bookdown. To submit, it is required that the bibliography is collected in a separate chapter at the end of the book.

In other words, instead of bibliography at the end of each chapter, there should be another chapter containing the bibliography lists, split into sections by chapter.

So, instead of:

```
Chapter 1
  Section 1.1
  Section 1.2
  Bibliography for Chapter 1
Chapter 2
  Section 2.1
  Section 2.2
  Bibliography for Chapter 2
```

The output should be

```
Chapter 1
  Section 1.1
  Section 1.2
Chapter 2
  Section 2.1
  Section 2.2
Bibliography
  Bibliography for Chapter 1
  Bibliography for Chapter 2
```

I am at loss how to produce that with bookdown, short of manually editing the resulting document. With LaTeX, several solutions come to mind, but I need to produce a single Word file for them.

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be great to have. How do you even control `Bibliography for Chapter 1` at the end of `Chapter 1`?